# FactoryBot factory for a Poro results in undefined method `build'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

I have a simple Poro, like so:

```
class Student
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name
  def initialize(data)
    @first_name = data[:first_name]
    @last_name = data[:last_name]
  end
end
```

A factory like so:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :student do
    first_name {"test first name"}
    last_name {"test last name"}

    # https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tips-for-using-factory-girl-without-an-orm
    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end
end
```

A test like so:

```
describe 'StudentSpec', type: :model do
  let(:student) {build(:student)}
  context 'attributes' do
    it 'respond' do
      expect(student).to respond_to(:first_name, :last_name)
    end
  end
end
```

But this results in `NoMethodError: undefined method 'build' for ....`

Based on https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tips-for-using-factory-girl-without-an-orm, it sounds like this should work. Wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of the spec file?
Also did you try to add `FactoryBot`?

```
let(:student) { FactoryBot.build(:student) }
```

Comment: It was the missing `require 'rails_helper'`. Thank you!